# Reading a text file line by line into a structure in c

Tags: c, data-structures, text-files

I am kind of new to c programming but I want to create a c function that can read contents of a text file line by line separated by the tab delimiter(\t) and store them into a data structure, then after clear the file but have still failed. My code is

```
struct Busy_list{
    int client_socket;
    char JOB[1024];
    int characters;
    int No_jobs;
    int IsReplace;
    int Priority;
};



char** PriorityEvaluator(int client_socket){
struct Busy_list Array;

FILE *Ufptr;
Ufptr = fopen("Unsorted_busy_list.txt","r+");
    for(int i;!EOF;i++){
        fscanf(Ufptr, "%d\t%s\t%d\t%d\t%d\n",&Array.client_socket,&Array.JOB,&Array.characters,&Array.No_jobs,&Array.IsReplace);
    }
    fclose(Ufptr);
}
```

**My Unsorted_busy_list file contains**

```
/*

4   double fish 4   1   0

5   double praise   6   2   0

5   replace peter 2-o,4-o   5   2   1

*/
```

Comment: That was an error.For Array.Priority = Array.IsReplace; . its supposed to set the priority to the value in Array.IsReplace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace your for loop with a while loop like this:

```
while((fscanf(Ufptr, "%d\t%s\t%d\t%d\t%d\n",&Arguments...)) != EOF){
}
```

Comment: does it mean I should not worry about the tabs(\t) between the raw data?

Comment: @MikeM you should set a termination for your for loop. I would reccomend to check for EOF(End of File) + you have to read your strings into your struct elements UNTIL each /t gets found.  How does your text file look?

Comment: I've edited my question and added how my text file looks like

Comment: Oh okey I understand. I updated my answer. That should work for your problem